# Why class LinkedList<E> does not implemet boolean isEmpty() method?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

LinkedList class implements following interfaces:

```
public class LinkedList<E>
extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
...
```

I noticed, that List interface contains isEmpty() method returning boolean:

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
int size();
boolean isEmpty();
...
```

My question is: Why LinkedList class doesn't implement isEmpty() method?

Secondly, is it allowed to one interface extends more than one interface?

Comment: This is a Java question and not a JavaScript question, right?

Comment: Because one of the super classes already implements `isEmpty()` and there is no need to change the implementation. You might want to read some of the topics from [the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedList` is a `AbstractSequentialList` which in terms is a  `AbstractList` which is a `AbstractCollection`. And that [`AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.isEmpty%28%29) already implements it in the following way:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}
```

and that logic is correct for the `LinkedList` and therefore it simply does not implement the method a second time.

Comment: Now, I see. Thanks.